# How to use HTML5 Canvas functional style

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, functional-programming

I'm doing some work with HTML5's Canvas element, and I'm wondering how to best implement my own, custom draw functions in a functional way. Each of these will need the context, but I can think of multiple ways to give it to them:

1. Add it as a parameter to each draw function call
2. Add it as a global variable
3. Call "getContext" in each draw method.
4. Extend the prototype of ´CanvasRenderingContext2D´.

I don't like to use global variables if I can avoid it, so I'm phasing out option 2. Option 3 requires way too much code duplication, so I also ignore that.

This leaves me with choice 1, which is how I would do it in a non-functional language and 4 which is in my opinion the cleanest approach, but I'm not entirely sure it won't lead to problems. How do you do it? Is there a reason why I shouldn't go with option 4?

To illustrate this, I'll add a code example for each of the remaining option. Here's option 1:

```
function drawPerson(context, ...) {
    context.fillRect(...);
    ...
}

$(function() {
    var context = $("#canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
    drawPerson(context, ...);
});
```

And here option 4:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawPerson = function(...) {
    this.fillRect(...);
    ...
}

$(function() {
    var context = $("#canvas")[0].getContext("2d");
    context.drawPerson(...);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to use a module which contains all drawing functions and initialize():

```
var Painter = (function(){

  var context = null;

  return {
    init : function(ctx){
      context = ctx;
    },
    drawPerson : function(){
      /* do stuff with context*/
    }
  }

})(); 

Painter.init($("canvas").getContext("2d"));
Painter.drawPerson();
```

That way there is only one global var, context is set only once and you don't mess with other objects.

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion. It wraps all functionality, leaving the context functionality exposed in only one place (initialization, but even that could be abstracted away). This means that changing from a 2D context to a 3D context, for example, would be much easier since you would only need to change the interface, not all your code using the interface. Even changing to an SVG interface would be simpler this way.